# Nano not registering all the option in the .nanorc file

Tags: syntax-highlighting, nano

so I came back on nano not long ago and tried to enable a few options in the ~/.nanorc file by writing the following:

```
include /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc
set autoindent
set tabsize 4
```

However, when I open a file as follow
`nano file_name`
so not using sudo, the only option that seems to show is the tabsize, there is no syntax highlighting, nor auto indents.

Also, the commented text appears in light blue, I don't know if that is by default or not.